# Passing class objects across different assembly versions

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies, reflection.emit, reflector

The scenario goes like this -

- I have an assembly say 'MyAssembly'. An interface say 'IMyInterface' is defined in this assembly.
- In the same assembly i have one class(MyClass) with a method define in it as :

> public void MyMethod( IMyInterface object ) {  }

- Now in my project, i have created an interface with the same name and exact properties as exposed by the interface "IMyInterface" in 'MyAssembly'.
- I have a class which extends this interface(the one which i have created in my project) and i want to pass the object of that class as a parameter to the method "MyMethod" in different assembly using reflection.

*Issue is -*

- When i try to invoke the method using reflection, i got this exception that **"Cannot convert object to type IMyInterface"**.

*Code -*

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyAssembly");
object classObject = myAssembly.CreateInstance("MyClass");
Type classType = myAssembly.GetType("MyClass");
MethodInfo myMethod = classType.GetMethod("MyMethod", BindingFlags.Instance);

// Creating an object of class in the latest assembly and need to pass this
// to method in assembly with different version.
ClassExtendingMyInterface obj= new ClassExtendingMyInterface ();

myMethod.Invoke(classObject, new object[] { obj});
```

If, i am getting it right, this is because object created is in different assembly and the parameter expected by the method is of its own assembly.

Another approach i thought of was to create my own dynamic method in the class which will accept the object of my class.

I have tried to google for and come across through **Reflection.Emit** or **RunSharp** to dynamically create your own class. But, we can use this only in our dynamically generated Assemblies but can't create dynamic methods or class in already existing assembly.

I know generating assemblies at runtime is ain't good approach. But i can't think of anything now. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are battling something called "Type identity", a very important DLL Hell counter-measure in the .NET framework.  A type isn't just identified by its namespace name and type name, it also includes attributes of the assembly from which it came from.  Specifically the assembly display name, [AssemblyVersion], [AssemblyCulture], PublicKeyToken and (indirectly) ProcessorArchitecture.  You can see the 'real' type name with the Type.AssemblyQualifiedName property.  The System.String class for example is `System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`

This stops you from faking a type in another assembly unless you can give that assembly the exact same attributes.  Much easier is to simply use the existing assembly, should be no problem in your case since you only use an interface.

Notably is that this requirement was relaxed somewhat in .NET 4.  Types that were auto-generated from a COM type library are equivalent if their name and [Guid] matches.  Which helped eliminate PIAs and implement the "Embed interop types" feature.  Nothing that applies in your case.

Comment: >Much easier is to simply use the existing assembly, should be no problem in your case since you only use an interface.

But i want my own implementation(way that interface is implemented) and want that object to be passed. But since that implementation i can't have in the existing assembly since that has already been deployed. Can't modify that assembly :( That's why i was trying to implement it in newer version of assembly and passing it as a parameter through reflection. Can i achieve that some other way if you can help.. thanks.. :)

Comment: I don't see why that's a problem, just use a copy of the deployed assembly and add it as a reference to your project.  No need for Reflection hacks.

Comment: I can't add a reference to the assmebly, since i need to load the assembly at runtime depending on some use cases.. I  have to load the assembly based on some user scenarios.. :(

Comment: It already works that way, assemblies only ever get loaded when you execute code that uses types from them.  No need for Reflection hacks.

Comment: Sorry couldn't get you. How can i inject my implementation of the interface into other assembly?

Comment: How can i use the type (in my case interface) from other assembly to extend the class (inheriting from interface) in my assembly..??

Comment: The only other option you have is to generate code dynamically at runtime with Reflection.Emit() or System.CodeDom.  This doesn't actually solve anything, it will fail just as miserably if the actual assembly's interface definition is incompatible.  Well, more miserably.

Comment: Reflection.Emit() or System.CodeDom only lets you allow to create methods in dynamic assembly. I am afraid that won't serve the purpose too for me i guess.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here:

> Now in my project, i have created an interface with the same name and exact properties as exposed by the interface "IMyInterface" in 'MyAssembly'.

There-in is the problem; it is not enough to declare a like-named interface. Types are scoped by their assembly; that is, to the CLR, a completely different interface.

Instead, add a **reference** to the original assembly, and implement the interface that is already defined. It should only be defined once.

Comment: I can't add a reference to the assmebly, since i need to load the assembly at runtime depending on some use cases.. :(

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, I believe you want to define your Interfaces in their own assembly, then reference the common interfaces assembly from within each of the other two. That way, each assembly is referencing the SAME Interface definition:

Create and build the MyInterfaces dll:

```
namespace MyInterfaces
{
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        void SharedMethod();
    }
}
```

Then create your first assembly in a different project, and set a reference to the dll created for MyInterfaces. Create your class, noting the "using" statements at the top of the module:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MyInterfaces;

namespace MyFirstProject
{
    public class MyClass1
    {
        public void MyMethod(IMyInterface SomeObject) { }
    }
}
```

Now, I believe your dynamic object creation should work, since both objects implement the same interface defined in "MyInterfaces".